# C++ executing a bash script which terminates and restarts the current process

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

So here is the situation, we have a C++ datafeed client program which we run ~30 instances of with different parameters, and there are 3 scripts written to run/stop them: start.sh stop.sh and restart.sh (which runs stop.sh and then start.sh).

When there is a high volume of data the client "falls behind" real time. We test this by comparing the system time to the most recent data entry times listed. If any of the clients falls behind more than 10 minutes or so, I want to call the restart script to start all the binaries fresh  so our data is as close to real time as possible.

Normally I call a script using System(script.sh), however the restart script looks up and kills the process using kill, BUT calling System() also makes the current program execution ignore SIGQUIT and SIGINT until system() returns.

On top of this if there are two concurrent executions with the same arguments they will conflict and the program will hang (this stems from establishing database connections), so I can not start the new instance until the old one is killed and I can not kill the current one if it ignores SIGQUIT.

Is there any way around this? The current state of the binary and missing some data does not matter at all if it has reached the threshold, I also can not just have the program restart itself, since if one of the instances falls behind, we want to restart all 30 of the instances (so gaps in the data are at uniform times). Is there a clean way to call a script from within C++ which hands over control and allows the script to restart the program from scratch?

FYI we are running on CentOS 6.3

Comment: instead of running the script from one of the 30 instances you could fork and do so in a new process that will exit after return from System or alternatively you could just have the instance that called system to terminate ?

Comment: It might be better to re-architect the client to check the time itself, and if it's falling too far behind, either skip enough data to catch up or restart itself somehow (re-`exec()`-ing itself would be one way, but it might be good to consider if any cleanup on files, connections, sockets, etc. needs to be done first...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `exec()` instead of `system()`.  It will replace your process with the new one.  Note there is a significant different in how `exec()` is called and how it behaves: `system()` passes its string argument to the system shell to run.  `exec()` actually executes an executable file, and you need to supply the arguments to the process one at a time, instead of letting the shell parse them apart for you.

Comment: execve() seems to be the right call. There are no arguments to pass as everything is contained within the script, so I am sending a null as executable arguments, however I am not sure how to set the environment variables when making the call..

Comment: You could try with an empty string for environment variables, or you could pass on the environment of the current process, which is found in `extern char **environ;`  In other words, `execve(filename, argv, environ);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents.

**Temporary solution:** Use SIGKILL.
**Long-term solution:** Optimize your code *or* the general logic of your service tree, using other system calls like exec or by rewritting it to use **threads**.

If you want better answers maybe you should post some code and or *degeneralize* the issue.